# How to make the text bold in navigation drawer after selection?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer and want to implement Google style i.e., when an item is selected, instead of using a indicator I want to make the text of the current item bold as it happens in Play Music or NewsStand. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that in the onItemSelected method of the ListView. Just use the following piece of code to make your text bold.

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    View rowView = view
    TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This doesn't work at all. OnItemSelectedListener doesn't actually listen for 'selection' in sense of checking one or more items in the drawer list. What it really does is only react on focusing the items (with trackpad or such). Otherwise, its never called.

Comment: This was meant for trackpad! You can just write the same code within OnItemClick method and achieve the same result !

Comment: Using OnItemClickListener has a problem - it doesn't make the TextView bold until the user actually clicks on it. But you need to make the currently selected item bold right from the start of the activity.

Comment: setSelection or setItemSelected method should help you do that first time and then onwards onItemClick will handle it

Comment: `setSelection()` only moves the ListView to the given item, it doesn't actually 'select' it (these methods are named in a very confusing way). I don't see a `setItemSelected()` method, but there is `setItemChecked()`. However, that doesn't fire the `OnItemClickListener`, because it doesn't actually click.

Comment: I thought thats what we wanted to achieve. Not sure what your trying to achieve. Open a new SO question probably? But if you this first time to be a click on listitem as well then performItemClick() might be of help.

Comment: I personally solved it using a custom adapter as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21336286/1064809 . I'm just pointing out that your answer doesn't provide a correct solution.

Comment: Just a note, this code will make all textviews with that id bold. I believe the correct behavior would be obtained by doing:
((TextView) view).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
instead