# Set bold text in navigation drawer just after creating it (before any selection)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer like those from Google apps(Play Music, Play Movies etc..)

Everything works just fine; my only problem is: I can't figure out how to set the text to **BOLD**, just after creating the drawer and before any selection or click is done!
I have no problem setting bold after the `onItemClick` is performed, but how to do it just after creating the drawer?
I've tried to get the View reference from the list inside the drawer, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

that's my navigation drawer code

```
        mNavDrawerStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.action_bar_list);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_navigation_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_item, mNavDrawerStrings));

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(0);

    NavigationDrawerItemClickListener navDrawerClickListener
        = new NavigationDrawerItemClickListener(this, mDrawerList, mDrawerLayout); 

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(navDrawerClickListener);

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow
        (R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: Can you not set it in the XML instead? for your drawer list item?

Comment: no, because i don't want ALL the text being bold.. but just the actual selected one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to preserve the selection so the selected item stays selected even after it goes outside the screen. For changing text color and item background you could use **Color / Drawable State List Resource** http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

However if you want to do more than that you would need to provide a custom adapter. Something like this:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private int selectedItem;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public void selectItem(int selectedItem){
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView)convertView).setTypeface(null, position == selectedItem ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and in onItemClick():

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    ((MyArrayAdapter)adapterView.getAdapter()).selectItem(position);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I found in a while looking for one.

Comment: Thank you. This works well. Now, I have both background highlighted (works only for v11+) and bold text (this solution, works for all version) for checked item in navigation drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple you can do this on **onItemSelected method of the ListView**. Just use this piece of code to make the text bold.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
View rowView = view
TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
}});
```

Comment: this works just if i select an item.. i want the text being bold just after creating the navigation drawer, before any selection

Comment: This will not work. The selection will not be preserved when the view goes out the screen. Don't forget a adapter reuses views. See my answer for more details

Comment: @marqss thank you for your help till now I thought this code will I tried your code it works perfectly thanks for your help.